# Compare values and determine position in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array which is called dataid and here is the `console.log` of my array:

[image]

and in my URL I stock myid: 
[image]

I want to make it so if I click on a span with the id "next", it send me in my URL the value of the next id in my array datatid. So first we need to determine the position of myid in my array and then determine which value is the next to send it in my URL.

This is what i tried:

```
  var newid = GetURLParameter('myid');
  console.log(newid);
  var dataid = localStorage.getItem("mesid");
  console.log(dataid);


  function nextticket(){
    var position = dataid.indexOf(newid)+1;
    console.log(dataid.indexOf(newid));
    console.log(position);
  }
```

and here is what I get: 
[image]

But the position are wrong!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried... And take a look at the `Array.prototype.indexOf()` method.

Comment: @cl3m i re-edit my post to show you what i tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localStorage stores strings, not arrays.
The position 10 in your output is because "4653" occurs at character position 10 in the string "5475,4831,4653,...".

You will need to split the string back into an array with something like this:

```
var position = dataid.split(',').indexOf(newid) + 1;
```

where the `split()` method as used here converts a comma-delimited string into an array.